# QGIS for mapping building vertices

Tags: qgis, vertices

Can QGIS be used to map a set of x, y points that layout a building?

And if so can it correct errors where vertices might be slightly out by pulling those which are close together?

I am considering attempting to write something that does this to correct any errors but I am unsure of where to start and thought I might see if there is anything existing that could do this.

An example of the building layout data is:

| name | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| room1 | 3.11 | 3.81 |
| room1 | 3.11 | 0 |
| room1 | 0 | 0 |
| room1 | 0 | 3.81 |

I don't know if this is enough data to get the general idea, but each room is included in the CSV file with all the x, y coordinates of the corners and I need to map them to a layout diagram of the building with all rooms aligned.

Comment: Do you have an example of x,y points?

Comment: I can add an example, they represent all the corner points where walls join in a building.

Comment: Your coordinate seem to be relative (one of your corner has a 0, 0 as coordinate ) QGIS will be able to plot this but not in relation to any real world position (and if each of your room have a 0, 0 coordinate you wont be able to place the room in their correct location relative to each other room)

Comment: Basically your coordinate seem to only give you that your room1 is a rectangle 3.11 width unit and 3.81 length unit...

Comment: Didn't read your question well, if you want to get a diagram of the building with all rooms aligned I think it will be easier to use any software that let you create rectangle of precise size using the dimension from your csv file. You may use illustrator/inkscape for pure graphic software or some CAD software, choose depending on witch you are the most confortable with.

Comment: The issue is the points are not accurate enough so when I am able to see the diagram I would need something that allows a threshold of some sort to be applied to bring the points closer together so there are no gaps.

The data probably isnt representative enough but the points should enable plotting, just some might be out, so two corner values might be a mm or so out

Comment: If the measurement are from the inside of the room the corner can't superpose as the wall has some thickness....

Comment: Providing sample data for more than one room would help understanding the problem and for testing purpose. Best share data, not a screenshot.